# How to create an Android Studio module in command line?

Tags: android, bash, android-studio, command-line

I'm trying to create a Bash script to automate the creation of some projects and modules to be used by Android Studio later. However, I can only find how to create *projects* using the command line, not modules:

```
android create project --gradle --gradle-version 1.5.0 --target "${BASE_API}" --name "${PROJECT_NAME}" --path "${PROJECT_NAME}" --activity DummyActivity --package it.doesnt.matter
```

How can I create a module inside the project created above using a Bash command?

Comment: gradle is the one that creates the module, you need to run the gradle task that is used to create modules. Just create a moudle in android studio using GUI, then check the gradle console to see the tasks being run

Comment: Gradle is the one that assembles the module, so try invoking gradlew from the command line? Perhaps this link (http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

A module is mostly just a directory of files. So:

1. Create a directory (`mkdir yourModule`)
2. Put whatever files you want in this directory, such as `build.gradle`
3. Script a solution to edit the `settings.gradle` file and add your module to the list of modules